# Alternative for "%p" format specifier

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm using a platform/compiler on an embedded system (specifically, XC8 on a PIC) that does not include the %p pointer address format specifier for printf().

For example:

```
printf("J: %f [@ 0x%p]\r\n", j, &j);
```

Would display the value and address of a variable called "j" with most compilers. However, according to the compiler documentation it does not include support for %p. Giving the error "invalid format specifier or type modifier".

So in that case, what is an alternative to printing the variable's address?

Comment: Try `%lx` and cast the address to `(unsigned long)`

Answer (score 3):

Nominally, you would use the `<inttypes.h>` header, the `uintptr_t` type, and the `PRIXPTR` or `PRIxPTR` format (first formally defined in C99 or ISO/IEC 9899:1999):

```
printf("J: %f [@ 0x%" PRIXPTR "]\r\n", j, (uintptr_t)&j);
```

However, if you don't have `%p`, you probably don't have those either, so you are likely to have to fall back on:

```
printf("J: %f [@ 0x%lX]\r\n", j, (unsigned long)&j);
```

This assumes `sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(void *)`; if not, you need to use an integer type such that the `sizeof(other_integer_type) == sizeof(void *)`.  You'll need to explain in detail the types on your machine if you can't find such a type.

Answer (score 3):

The `%p` format is normally implemented by the `printf` function in the runtime library, not in the compiler. The distinction can be important for implementations where the compiler and library don't necessarily come from the same vendor or other source. (Some compilers may optimize `printf` calls with literal format strings; thanks to chux for pointing this out.)

As Matt McNabb's comment suggests, you can very probably convert the pointer to `unsigned long` and use `%lx` to print it. I'd probably use something like:

```
printf("J: %f [@ 0x%lx]\r\n", j, (unsigned long)&j);
```

It's possible this could fail if (a) pointers are wider than `unsigned long` or (b) the conversion from a pointer type to `unsigned long` loses information. I've worked on some odd systems, but I've never seen one that would violate either of these assumptions.

Since your code probably isn't meant to be portable anyway, you can check the sizes of pointers and `unsigned long` on your platform. If you're feeling paranoid, you can add something like:

```
assert(sizeof (unsigned long) >= sizeof (void*));
```

just to be (almost) sure that the conversion won't lose information.

Comment: "The %p format is implemented by the printf function in the runtime library, not in the compiler." is not necessarily so.  PIC compilers (depending on which one) analyze the constant format string at compile time and form the needed function calls.

Comment: @chux: Good point. gcc can do similar transformations, though not quite as aggressively; for example, `printf("hello\n")` might result in code equivalent to `puts("hello");`

Comment: Compilers for embedded platforms like this optimization to avoid bringing in the whole `printf()` function - which in general, is quite large.